# Best way to pull data from list for .net app

Tags: 2013, list, export

We are fairly new to SharePoint 2013. We need to pull some data from a List Library and use it in a .net application. How is the best way to do this? Examples would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advanced,

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Microsoft.SharePoint` namespace and the `SPSite`, `SPWeb`, `SPList` classes. Example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms457534.aspx).